# C while loop infinite loop EOF not working

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, eof, infinite

I am having problem with `EOF` in my while loop. It does not seem to simply end when `EOF` is entered but rather does this...

How can I fix it and have the while loop stop and move on. Thanks.

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <limits.h>

    void findLargestandSmallest(int integer, int* largest, int* smallest, int* average, int count);

    int main(void)
    {
        //Local Declaration
        int integer;
        int largest;
        int smallest;
        int average;
        int count; // number count

        //Starting statemnets
        smallest = INT_MAX;
        largest = INT_MIN;
        count = 0;

        // Starting prompts
        printf("\nHello this program will take in intagers and print");
        printf("\nout the largest, smallest and avarage of integers");
        printf("\nenterd int.");
        printf("\nPlease enter in a integer ");

        while (scanf("%d", &integer) != EOF)
        {
            if (integer != EOF)
            {
                count++;
                findLargestandSmallest(integer, &largest, &smallest, &average, count);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n \n");
            }
        }

        printf("\nThe largest number entered is %d and the smallest", largest);
        printf("\nwas %d and the average of all the numbers is %d\n", smallest, average);
        return 0;
    }

    void findLargestandSmallest(int integer, int *largest, int *smallest, int *average, int count)
    {
        int x; // just a holder variable 

        // finds average
        x = 0;
        x += integer;
        *average = (x / count);

        // Finds smallest and largest
        if (integer <= *smallest)
        {
            *smallest = integer;
        }
        if (integer >= *largest)
        {
            *largest = integer;
        }
        printf("Enter another integer or <EOF> to quit ");
        return;
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0307.png
```

UPDATE: I found out what I was doing wrong. Its simple. In the while loop `while(scanf("%d", &integer) != EOF)` don't set it like that but like this `(scanf("%d", &integer))` EOF is understood. To simply call it in DOS use use "Ctrl+Z" on your last input. i.e "number^Z" is how it will look after using "Ctrl+Z" Also here is the better and working code for this problem for anyone else that runs into this.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void findLargestandSmallest(int integer, int* largest, int* smallest);

int main(void)
{
    //Local Declaration
    int integer;
    int largest;
    int smallest;
    int average;
    int sum;
    int count;

    //Starting statemnets
    smallest = INT_MAX;
    largest = INT_MIN;
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;

    // Starting prompts
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n-  Hello, this program will take in intagers and print -");
    printf("\n-  out the largest, smallest, and avarage  of the      -");
    printf("\n-  integers enterd.                                    -");
    printf("\n-  NOTE: To quit: use \"Ctrl+Z\" on the last integer     -");
    printf("\n-  you enter i.e \"number^z\"                        -");
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\nEnter integers\n");

    // Finds largest and smallest number
    while (scanf("%d", &integer))
    {
        sum += integer;
        count++;
        findLargestandSmallest(integer, &largest, &smallest);
    }

    // Finds average
    count--;
    average = (sum / count);

    // End prompts
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nThe largest number entered was %d, the smallest", largest);
    printf("\nwas %d, and the average of all the numbers is %d.", smallest, average);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nGoodbye\n");
    return 0;
}

void findLargestandSmallest(int integer, int *largest, int *smallest)
{
    if (integer < *smallest)
    {
        *smallest = integer;
    }
    if (integer > *largest)
    {
        *largest = integer;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Enter another integer or <EOF> to quit ");`should be at the end of the while loop and not at the end of the `findLargestandSmallest` function.

Comment: How do you cause `EOF`?  By typing in "EOF", Ctrl-D or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I found out what I was doing wrong. Its simple. In the while loop while(scanf("%d", &integer) != EOF) don't set it like that but like this (scanf("%d", &integer)) EOF is understood. To simply call it in DOS use use "Ctrl+Z" on your last input. i.e "number^Z" is how it will look after using "Ctrl+Z" Also here is the better and working code for this problem for anyone else that runs into this.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void findLargestandSmallest(int integer, int* largest, int* smallest);

int main(void)
{
    //Local Declaration
    int integer;
    int largest;
    int smallest;
    int average;
    int sum;
    int count;

    //Starting statemnets
    smallest = INT_MAX;
    largest = INT_MIN;
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;

    // Starting prompts
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n-  Hello, this program will take in intagers and print -");
    printf("\n-  out the largest, smallest, and avarage  of the      -");
    printf("\n-  integers enterd.                                    -");
    printf("\n-  NOTE: To quit: use \"Ctrl+Z\" on the last integer     -");
    printf("\n-  you enter i.e \"number^z\"                        -");
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\nEnter integers\n");

    // Finds largest and smallest number
    while (scanf("%d", &integer))
    {
        sum += integer;
        count++;
        findLargestandSmallest(integer, &largest, &smallest);
    }

    // Finds average
    count--;
    average = (sum / count);

    // End prompts
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nThe largest number entered was %d, the smallest", largest);
    printf("\nwas %d, and the average of all the numbers is %d.", smallest, average);
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nGoodbye\n");
    return 0;
}

void findLargestandSmallest(int integer, int *largest, int *smallest)
{
    if (integer < *smallest)
    {
        *smallest = integer;
    }
    if (integer > *largest)
    {
        *largest = integer;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns the number of elements successfully converted. If it can't convert any, it returns 0. `EOF` is only returned for end-of-file (on Unix a Control-D).

So you should modify your program to save the return value from scanf and then test it for 0 and `EOF` separately.

It is also pointless to compare the `integer` variable with `EOF`, since all you can possibly know about `EOF` is that it is a negative integer. Read the `scanf` manual page and understand what it does and what it returns when and where. That'll solve the puzzle. :-)

Alright, some more hints. Can you make sense of this?

```
for (;;) {
    int successfully_converted = scanf("%d", &integer);

    if (successfully_converted == EOF) {
        /* Do something when the user is tired of typing. */
        puts("Thank you for an enjoyable game.\n");
        exit(0);
    } else if (successfully_converted == 0) {
        puts("This didn't look like an integer\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        /* Do something with integer. */
    }
}
```

Comment: In particular, it seems you are not doing anything to skip the whitespace that exists between numbers - so you scan the first number, and then every `scanf()` after that returns 0, because it can't scan a number when the next character is a space or new line, and 0 never matches `EOF`, so you have an infinite loop...

Comment: Well it don't fully understand how to do that... Also one of the values I want to enter in the scnaf is 0.
I am still getting the hang of and computer programing in general. Could you try and elaborate in your explanation?

Comment: @twalberg `scanf("%d"...` skips leading white-space.  Skipping white-space is _not_ the OP's problem.

Comment: @chux Yeah, you're right, now that I think about it again. However, any non-whitespace character in the input that cannot be scanned as an integer will cause a problem like this....

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing the integer value with EOF
. You are comparing the scanf result with EOF..
Here as you enter 1 value each time, scanf result will be 1.

So evrrytime the while loop condition fails and infinite loop is generated. 
Also if you EOF then what character would you enter to end the loop???
So EOF should not be used.

So I would suggest you to use do while loop

do

{

scanf("%d",&integer);

....

...
printf("enter 1 to continue");

scanf("%d",&check);

}while(check == 1);

Comment: I have a doubt. Why do you use EOF??? What character will you enter to end the loop?so this might be a reason ....

Comment: Have edited my solution based on above comments.. kindly check

Answer (score 0):

Test the result of `scanf()` against EOF, 0, and 1.

```
int cnt;
while ((cnt = scanf("%d", &integer)) == 1) {
  count++;
  findLargestandSmallest(integer, &largest, &smallest, &average, count);
}
if (cnt == 0) {
  printf("Something other than an integer was entered.\n");
}
else if (cnt == EOF) {
  printf("EOF or I/O Error occurred.\n");
}
// Add the following for debug if desired
else {
  printf("Should _never get here!\n");
}
...
```